# How to continue loop after 404 response in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, http-status-code-404, httpresponse

I looked up whether you can just ignore the 404 response and go ahead with your loop but I did not find a solution regarding to Angular, so I want to ask this question here.

I have the following code:

```
  for(let order of orders){
      this.api.getURL(order.resource_url).then(data =>
          this.detail = data;
      );
      // Do something with this.detail ...
  }
```

If the request returns a 404 response, the loop should go to the next order and check whether the request returns a correct response or an error again. Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When server responses 404  you receives an exception. To avoid it, you have to catch that error:

```
for(let order of orders){
  this.api.getURL(order.resource_url).then(data => {
    this.detail = data;
  }, error => {
    // error has been caught
  });
}
```

**UPDATED**

You are struggling, because you are trying to use asynchronous api in a synchronous way :)
Try to filter failed responses and then do your computations:

```
Promise.all(
 orders.map(order => this.api.getURL(order.resource_url).catch(() => null))
).then(responses => {
  const successfulResponses = responses.filter(response => response != null)
  for(let data of successfulResponses) {
    // your following code
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer! Do you know whether I can switch to the next order in my for loop? Because if the page was not found, the code after that should not be executed since the property ```this.detail``` would be undefined.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the new answer. I will try it and let you know whether it is working!

Answer (score 1):

As shumih said, you have to catch the error, in the error section you can then call `continue;` (direct jump to next loop-run), to make sure it executes the next run of your loop.
The line: `this.detail = data` should not be executed anyways when you get a 404 because there's no promise returned, so it doesn't get into this then({}) section.

Comment: If I call ```continue;``` in the error section, I get the error: ```Jump target cannot cross function boundary.